# Reading values from property files in Spring MVC using java based anotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, config

I'm using Spring 3.1+ version in my Spring MVC project. I have read a bunch of articles  of how to use property files in code and i tryied a few solutions but non of them is working. For example something like this http://websystique.com/spring/spring-propertysource-value-annotations-example/

[image: Project tree]

Following is communication.properties located in src/main/resources

```
doniiesuser.url=localhost
doniiesuser.port=8080
```

Configuration class, i reused the class with the spring mvc configuration and i tried adding a different class only for the property sources thing.

```
<!-- language: java -->
package com.doniies.doniiesweb.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.doniies.doniiesweb.controller", "com.doniies.doniiesweb.services"})
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:communication.properties"})
public class MVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

 // more beans and code

    /**
     * Ensures that placeholders are replaced with property values
     */
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

where new changes to add property files reading is **@PropertySource** and **PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer** method

Finally to i want to use this properties in a @Service or @Controller class (trying 2 solutions, using placeholders ${key} and Environment class)

```
@Service
public class UserRepositoryUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserRepositoryUserDetailsService.class);

    @Value( "${doniiesuser.url}" )
    private String doniiesuserUrl;

    @Value( "${doniiesuser.port}" )
    private String doniiesuserPort;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    //More things...

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("WEB - placeholder @value: " + doniiesuserUrl);
        System.out.println("WEB - using env @value: " + environment.getProperty("doniiesuser.port"));

        logger.info("WEB - placeholder @value: " + doniiesuserUrl);
        logger.info("WEB - using env @value: " + environment.getProperty("doniiesuser.port"));

    }

    //....
}
```

and log display the following when i run it in my local tomcat server:

```
WEB - placeholder @value: ${doniiesuser.url}
WEB - using env @value: null
INFO - WEB - placeholder @value: ${doniiesuser.url}
INFO - WEB - using env @value: null
```

Am i missing something? Is there something i do not understand?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess that after 5 month you must have solved this problem somehow.

I'd suggest you to check that your "WebAppInitializer" is loading all your configuration files, something you could do with:

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
rootContext.scan("com.doniies.doniiesweb.config");
```

Another thing to check is your "PropertiesConfiguration" file in case it's causing some conflict.

I have tested a configuration, similar to the one in the article you posted, using Spring 4.2 and it's working ok.

Hope this helps!